# "Our content is all about geography quizzes" or "our content are all about geography quizzes"?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, subject-verb-agreement

"Our content is all about geography articles" or "our content are all about geography articles"?

Which one is correct?

I thought the second one is but when I type it, the *Grammarly* tells me it's wrong and should change `are` to `is`, but why? How can `is` + `articles` works?

Comment: Would you mind telling us where your question is from? I think your phrases are slightly forced, and they might not be what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verb needs to agree with the subject of the sentence. The subject of your sentence is "our content", which is singular. So, the verb should be singular: "is".

The verb does not need to agree with an object or with a subject complement. In your sentence, "all about geography articles" is the subject complement. "Geography articles" is the object of "about".

Comment: Oh, thanks. BTW, `content` can only be used as a singular noun, right?

Comment: @AGamePlayer Right.

Comment: @BenKovitz In the context of the question you are, of course, correct. One does not speak of "the contents" of a course of study or an article but can speak of "the contents" of a book, a magazine, a box or other container. For example "The contents of this suitcase are my clothes and personal effects"  is perfectly correct t.